# How to round a TabBar and add a shadow to it

Tags: c#, maui

I'm trying to make a TabBar like the one in the picture below
[image]

But I can't find a way to do it. I looked at similar articles on xamarin, but because of some differences it doesn't work

Comment: maybe you can get some idea by looking at this example 
https://github.com/sattasundar/maui-starbucks-ui he has a custom tab bar, but seems to be easier then what you want, anyway worth having a check

Comment: *" but because of some differences it doesn't work"* If you add to question the code you tried (as text not an image), plus a link to a xamarin article, plus the exact message for any errors, then people could help you adapt that for Maui.